# How to get windows vCenter server's license expiration date and license type using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, vmware, vcenter, pyvmomi

Can someone please suggest me a module which gets vCenter server's license expiration date and license type.

I tried to search from https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples but could not find any.

I need information(Displayed in attachment) using python.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRK4J.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the [`LicenseManager`](https://code.vmware.com/doc/preview?id=4206#/doc/vim.LicenseManager.html) for this. Try using `si.RetrieveContent().licenseManager` and call methods from there.

Note that the `LicenseManager` is deprecated starting vSphere 6.0, but according to [this answer](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2558604#2558604) they'll still be around for some time and it looks like the CIS API isn't documented even for vSphere 6.5.